# Sig. letters will not show up on box plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, letter, significance, tukey

```
   WD.fit<-emmeans(WD.mod,~POST*PLANTING.DATE)
   WD.fit
   WD.cld<-cld(WD.fit,decreasing=TRUE,adjust='Tukey',Letters=LETTERS,reversed = T)#gives the letters 
   WD.cld

   anova <- aov(DENSITY ~ POST+PLANTING.DATE+POST*PLANTING.DATE, data = WDat56DAPOST)
   summary(anova)

   tukey <- TukeyHSD(anova)
   print(tukey)
   cld <- multcompLetters4(anova, tukey)
   print(WD.cld)


    ggplot(WDat56DAPOST) +
     aes(x = POST, y = DENSITY, fill = PLANTING.DATE) +
    geom_boxplot(coef=0,outlier.shape = NA) +
     scale_fill_hue(direction = 1) +
     labs(x = "POST", y = "DENSITY", title = "Weed Density 28 Days After First POST") +
     theme_classic() +
     theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16L, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5), axis.title.y =  
     element_text(size = 12L, face = "bold"), axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12L, face = "bold"))
    geom_text(data = WD.cld, aes(x = POST, y = DENSITY, label = cld)
```

geom_text code did not work

Comment: Welcome to SO! As is your code is missing a `+` to "add" the `geom_text` layer to your ggplot. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared using `dput()` so that we can run your code. I would also help if you could describe more clearly what't the issue, e.g. do you get any error messages? As is we can only guess what's the issue.